# java method help

Tags: java

I need help with a method. The method I've written is:

```
public void readBook(String bookReader, String book);
```

The method needs to show both strings of the argument in the console. What else do I need to do to get the method to work?

Comment: Is that a method ? It looks like a declaration to me. Can you publish the complete method implementation ?

Comment: sorry, what i ment was ive defined the method (above) but how do i get the method to print the strings (of the argument) in the console?

Comment: Is this homework?  Are you asking us to write it for you?

Comment: nope im trying to learn how to write methods

Comment: Sun has some great beginning Java tutorials here, probably best to start with the documentation: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/index.html

Comment: @Jon: Well, I've suggested him that particular link at least two times before (also once in one of his deleted topics). I'm afraid that suggesting it once again ain't going to help more :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've done the above i.e.

```
public void readBook(String bookReader, String book){ 
    System.out.println("Book Reader: " + bookReader);
    System.out.println("Book:" + book); 
}
```

...you need to call it from your main method (or wherever you want) like so:

```
readBook("The Book Reader", "The Books Name");
```

Answer (score 8):

```
public void readBook(String bookReader, String book){
    System.out.println("Book Reader: " + bookReader);
    System.out.println("Book:" + book);
}
```

This should do it. I recomend google for questions like this though.

Comment: In this case, it's not about googling for answers, but actually learning Java.

Answer (score 2):

in your method body, use

```
System.out.println( bookReader );
System.out.println( book );
```

For printing them on separate lines

Comment: thanks mate, i was thinking about that but didnt know if it was possible to do it with methods

Comment: @noob11 Looks like you got a lack of some fundamental concepts here.

Comment: @Willi: Everybody starts somewhere

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to print the variables, try :

```
String SPACE = " ";  // can make it class level constant.
String separator = SPACE;  // can have different string, space is just an example
System.out.println(bookReader + separator + book);
```

There are lot of ways to embelish it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to print to the console

First:

```
System.out.print("Your string here");
```

Second:

```
System.out.println("Your string here");
```

The difference between the two is that the second will automatically place the output on a new line in the console.